Similarity index in R
I want to create a code that tells me which is the nearest neighbor in Euclidean distance according to a certain number of variables. I have created this code but it has the disadvantage that it does not exclude the variable itself.
I would like to keep the modality of being able to easily modify the number of neighbors in the code.
data(iris)

iris_subset <- iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")]

find_closest_species <- function(flower_row, all_data, row_index, num_closest = 1) {
  distances <- sqrt(rowSums((t(t(all_data) - flower_row))^2))
  
  sorted_distances <- sort(distances, index.return = TRUE)
  
  closest_indices <- sorted_distances$ix[sorted_distances$ix != row_index][1:num_closest]
  
  iris$Species[closest_indices]
}

iris$closest_species <- apply(iris_subset, 1, function(row, idx) {
  paste(find_closest_species(row, iris_subset, idx), collapse = ", ")
}, idx = seq_len(nrow(iris)))



"I have created this code but it has the disadvantage that it does not exclude the variable itself." I don't understand which variable needs to be excluded.

the output shows that variable Species and the variable closest_species are the same. I want the nearest neighbor, nor the observation itself.

The FNN package has some nearest neighbor functions.

You appear to be calculating distance as the square root of the sum of the squared distances between two observations. That's Euclidean distance - you can do that with R's built-in dist() function, which will make a distance matrix for you.
Every row and every column of the distance matrix corresponds to a row of your data. So if you look within a row of the matrix, the lowest value will be in the column corresponding to the observation that is closest to the observation for that row.
If you don't want to look at the distance between an observation and itself (which is zero), you exclude the diagonal of the matrix. You can do that by either throwing out zeros when you check values, or by setting all diagonal values of the matrix to NA ahead of time with diag(mymatrix) <- NA. Sometimes you may also find it helpful to use diag(mymatrix) <- Inf if you're using a function that doesn't handle NA values well.
Here's how you could rewrite your function to use a distance matrix. I assume that when you say you don't want to match something to itself you mean the same observation to itself, not the same species to itself (since there are multiple observations for each species).
# The iris dataset contains multiple rows for each species. Give each instance a unique name consisting of its species and its row number
iris$name <- paste0(iris$Species,1:nrow(iris))

# Make a distance matrix, and name the dimensions
distances <- as.matrix(dist(iris[,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")],method='euclidean'))
dimnames(distances) <- list(iris$name,iris$name)

# This function assumes "dists" is a NAMED vector of distances for one observation
# It also may return more neighbors than requested if there are ties
closest_neighbors <- function(dists,num_closest) {
  elig <- !is.na(dists) & (dists > 0) # Make sure we exclude the diagonal whether it's set to NA or left as 0
  cutoff <- head(sort(dists[elig]),num_closest)[num_closest]
  keep <- elig & dists <= cutoff
  return(paste(names(dists)[keep],collapse=', '))
}

# The distance matrix rows/columns are already named,
# so the vector passed to closest_neighbors() by apply() is named
iris$closest3 <- apply(distances,1,closest_neighbors,num_closest=3)

# Look at results
head(iris[,c('name','closest3')],5)

     name                               closest3
1 setosa1            setosa5, setosa40, setosa41
2 setosa2 setosa10, setosa13, setosa35, setosa46
3 setosa3  setosa7, setosa13, setosa46, setosa48
4 setosa4           setosa30, setosa31, setosa48
5 setosa5            setosa1, setosa18, setosa38

As expected, there are some cases where ties mean there aren't exactly three closest neighbors, but other than that I think this approach achieves what you asked about:

You can vary the number of neighbors returned
Observations are prevented from matching to themselves by excluding the diagonal

